# weblogic sample/example code

Tags: java, installation, weblogic, sample

I have tried a couple of different installs from here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-for-dev-1703574.html

But i dont get any sample java code/apps in them

They keep saying use "complete installation" or see the below screens, but I dont even get to select the checkboxes - it just installs oepe and weblogic, but no samples!

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/install_screens.htm

Comment: Where are you looking? They should be in something like: /opt/ora/mw/wlserver/samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a blank domain
and then extend the domain with the template

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24495/templates.htm#CIHHFEAG

by default wlserver/samples has nothing in it

after creating the domain - the source was found in

C:\share\weblogic\wls1212\user_projects\applications\examplesdomain\examples\src